# killing a service in android?

Tags: android, android-service

In my app I am trying to use a Service to redirect my app to another Application.

I am starting this Service in onPause method and I am trying to stop this Service in onResume method, but the Service still keeps running and it redirects automatically.

```
protected void onPause() {
    Intent in = new Intent(HelloappActivity.this,SimpleService.class);
    in.putExtra("qwe", k);      
    startService(in);
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume() {
    stopService(new Intent(HelloappActivity.this,SimpleService.class));
}
```

so how should I stop this service?

Comment: any reason you redirect from service not from activity?

Comment: "In my app I am trying to use a Service to redirect my app to another Application" -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: my app allows users to select any 1 installed app  and tat app starts running and the user is blocked from accessing any other app from there on. so i am using the service to keep track of the present app and the app tat the user initially selected and if these two are different then redirect takes place.

Comment: Have you tried having your service call  `stopSelf ();` ?